# Count the minutes in each 30 minute block for a given start_time and end_time

Tags: python, pandas

**Question:**

I have the below data frame:

```
data_1 = {
    'ID':['123'],
    "Start_time" :[pd.Timestamp('08:40')],
    "End_time" :[pd.Timestamp('10:01')]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
```

[image]

Each row represents a meeting's `start_time` and `end_time` and I want to transform it to the below data set so that I can get the total minute count in each 30 minute block where each block is bounded by 0th or 30th minute of an hour (for example, 8:30-9:00 instead of 8:40-9:10) .

[image]

---

**What I tried:**

The only way which I could think of creating the data frame is by using the below variables through a for loop, where `is_start_time` and `is_end_time` denotes if the `new_start` belongs to the start/end of the meeting, respectively (there should also be some logic to assign the above two variables).

```
8.40 - {new_start :8.40, block_start :8.30, block_end :9.00, is_start_time :1, is_end_time :0}

9.10 - {new_start :9.10, block_start :9.00, block_end :9.30, is_start_time :0, is_end_time :0}

9.40 - {new_start :9.40, block_start :9.30, block_end :10.00, is_start_time :0, is_end_time :0}

10.10 - {new_start :10.10, block_start :10.00, block_end :10.30, is_start_time :0, is_end_time :1}
```

and then calculating the `num_minutes` using the variables `is_start_time` and `is_end_time`.

```
if is_start_time  = 1  and is_end_time = 0:
      num_minutes = block_end -new_start
else if is_start_time  = 0  and is_end_time = 1 :
      num_minutes = end_time - block_start 
else :
      num_minutes =30
```

This seems like a lengthy process and I will have to iterate through each meeting record to derive this. Can someone suggest a better approach for this using pandas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the followig function to be applied to each row:

```
def rowProc(row):
    t1 = row.Start_time.floor('30T')
    t2 = row.End_time.ceil('30T')
    rng = pd.date_range(t1, t2, freq='30T')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': row.ID, 'Start_time': row.Start_time,
        'End_time': row.End_time, 'From': rng[:-1].strftime('%H:%M'),
        'To': rng[1:].strftime('%H:%M'), 'num_minutes': 30})
    df.iloc[0, 5] = 30 - int((row.Start_time - t1).total_seconds() / 60)
    df.iloc[-1, 5] = df.iloc[-1, 5] - int((t2 - row.End_time).total_seconds() / 60)
    df.insert(3, 'Block', df.From + '-' + df.To)
    df.drop(columns=['From', 'To'], inplace=True)
    return df
```

Then apply it and concatenate partial results:

```
result = pd.concat(df_1.apply(rowProc, axis=1).values, ignore_index=True)
```

For a source DataFrame containing:

```
    ID          Start_time            End_time
0  123 2021-12-02 08:40:00 2021-12-02 10:01:00
1  234 2021-12-02 10:20:00 2021-12-02 11:00:00
2  345 2021-12-02 11:10:00 2021-12-02 11:24:00
```

I got:

```
    ID          Start_time            End_time        Block  num_minutes
0  123 2021-12-02 08:40:00 2021-12-02 10:01:00  08:30-09:00           20
1  123 2021-12-02 08:40:00 2021-12-02 10:01:00  09:00-09:30           30
2  123 2021-12-02 08:40:00 2021-12-02 10:01:00  09:30-10:00           30
3  123 2021-12-02 08:40:00 2021-12-02 10:01:00  10:00-10:30            1
4  234 2021-12-02 10:20:00 2021-12-02 11:00:00  10:00-10:30           10
5  234 2021-12-02 10:20:00 2021-12-02 11:00:00  10:30-11:00           30
6  345 2021-12-02 11:10:00 2021-12-02 11:24:00  11:00-11:30           14
```